# left join with some intersect

Tags: php, mysql

i have three tables: A, B and C, B is the table necessary to break the many to many relationship:

```
table A   table B   table C
-------   -------   -------
id        id        id
....      id_A      ...
....      id_C      ...
```

and i have two multiselect html object two display the results, in the second one i need the intersection of both, that is a simple inner join.

the problem is the first one, i need to display there all items are available, so not the same items could be displayed in both.

in a first time, in order to fill the first multiselect i just do a table A left join with table B where the B.id is null, that was ok:

```
select * from tableA as A
left join tableB as B on A.id = B.id_A
where B.id_A is null
```

but after that i realized that there is a problem, because if there another relation AC, this relation will appear in both multiselect, so i tried:

```
select * from tableA as A
left join tableB as B on A.id = B.id_A
where B.id_A is null or B.id_C != $id
```

and doesn't work, i need a way to display en the first multiselect only the available and not repeat options every time i change the id_C

i hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "B is the table necessary to break" the relationship. More accurately, the intermediary table *defines* the N:N relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

SELECT tableC.field1, tableC.field2
FROM tableC
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableC.ID = tableB.ID_C
AND tableB.ID_A = $ID_A
WHERE tableB.ID_A IS NULL
GROUP BY tableC.field1, tableC.field2

Comment: select * from tableA as A
left join tableB as B on A.id = B.id_A and B.id_C = $id
where B.id_A is null

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `distinct` before the `*` like this: `select distinct * from ...`

Comment: DISTINCT helps when there's a column that's got repeated data. I'm thinking the data in the A or C tables may be repeating data, which isn't something you'd normally want to have. What I'm saying is that this approach might mask out a larger issue with bad data, and that there may very well be another issue at hand that should be addressed.